# Trying to install latest nodejs on heroku and render using Docker

Tags: node.js, heroku, render.com

I've been unsuccessfully trying to get the latest nodejs installed on heroku (I also tried render, with the same result).

Bit of a backstory: I have a particular dependency that I need the latest version of (so apt-get, using the `heroku-community/apt` buildpack, is out of the question, as it returns an older version). I thus opted for a Docker image instead. But, this means I also need to manually install the latest version of nodejs in that Docker image (I have some other dependencies that rely on node >= 16).

I've tried nvm (**updated**):

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get -yq update && apt-get -yq install curl
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash \
    && . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install 18
```

I've tried this in many, many different forms - the above is the closest I've gotten - nodejs gets downloaded but subsequently I get the following error:

```
error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash     && . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh     && nvm install 18" did not complete successfully: exit code: 11
```

The following:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg
RUN mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
RUN NODE_MAJOR=18
RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nodejs -y
```

Throws the following error on either platform:

```
E: The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_.x nodistro Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I'm aware of some fixes for this, such as:

```
RUN rm /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
```

These files are not found (at least not in those locations) on these platforms.

This would be a lot easier on a local machine :-) Any ideas on how to do this on platforms such as heroku or render?